# iOS Creat image from UIImageView and couple of UIViews attached on it

Tags: ios

I want to create an image from an `UIImageView` and couple of `UIViews` attached on it.

The image will look exactly as the screenshot, but if I just take the screenshot, the image is created exactly the same size of screen. Now, if I create the image with bigger dimension, the screenshot is being distorted, though the `UIImageView` image is a really high resolution image.

So, I think this problem will be solved, if I create an image with the components other than just saving the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it.

(it doesn't matter how many views you have)

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
[self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: you'll have to consider the other frame sizes separatly though (retina, iphone 5)

Comment: Thanks buddy, here I can create the image. But, the image will take the size of my view. Now, my view is 300 X 300. But, the image, assigned to it is of 600 X 600. Can I create the image sized 600 X 600 without distortion?

Comment: I believe that wouldn't be possible. Because if you scale the "screenshot" you would double the resolution so it would not be a perfect image.